# Cannot access variable value of Parameterised constructor variable value

Tags: c#, variables, c#-4.0

I have a parameterized constructor like below.

```
public abc(string c)
{
   a=c;
}
```

Then i have Button Event Handler like below.

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(c);
}
```

So when i do this , When Message box appears it shows nothing it was blank. What is the error ? I have debugged the code i found that constructor has value but message box is not getting value it is null.

Comment: where is `c` defined?

Answer (score 1):

As per the provided code in the question, i think you are trying to access local variable 'c' which has scope just for the constructor, outside the constructor. You can show variable 'a', which is a field of class 'abc' having scope for the class in the MessageBox.Show() method to get the same result. If you have a different declaration of c which you are trying to access in Button click event, make sure its been initialized properly.